# How to restart and make all containers to use the latest images, and remove the none images?

Tags: debian, docker

I use this command to delete all `<none>` docker images:

```
docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi
```

But then I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 00d1bd49dd01 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container a36783d86ab9
```

I tried to restart all containers using this command, thinking that they would use the latest image when they get restarted:

```
docker restart $(docker ps -q)
```

But that made no difference.

So, how can I forcefully tell all containers to switch to the latest images, and remove `<none>` images?

Answer (score 1):

> thinking that they would use the latest image when they get restarted

that's the opposite of what docker is designed for, and how it works!

So, no. Starting a container *restarts the container*. It doesn't pull any new images! The whole point of docker is that images are immutable; you need to explicitly remove a container, and make a new one based on a different image.

Comment: I don't want it to `pull` the new image. The new image is already there. I have `image-name <none>` and `image-name latest` both on my local machine. And in my `docker-compose.yml` I have explicitly specified to use the `latest` tag. But when I restart it and try to delete the `<none>` image it can't remove it and points to that container.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I didn't. You assume that restarting a container makes it use a new image. It doesn't, by design.